# Gatling test - exceeds JVM code size limits. Method <init>'s code too large

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I have a huge gatling test scrip from recording a big application. When I try to run it, I am getting an error,

`Could not write class AssociateAll because it exceeds JVM code size limits. Method <init>'s code too large!`

I am trying to go around it. How do i break a scala test for gatling to multiple small files, so I am not getting the error.

I am using Gatling verion 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution.

Created another scala class and included that in main scala class.